# Could malware be persisting on a tablet after factory reset?

Tags: factory-reset

Is there any other solution for my Sprint Slate besides factory reset?  When using certain aps the screen goes black even though sound can still be heard, it stutters and lags and freezes.  I used to be able to restart it and that would work but now even that doesn't seem to work.  Also when I tap icons the one that opens is often not the one I chose.  It worked for a while after the factory reset but now it is back to the way it was before.

Comment: The body of your question doesn't support the existence of a malware, let alone a persistent one. How did you conclude a persistent malware could be behind the problems you are facing?

Comment: If not Malware then what could be responsible?  I don't really care what the problem is-I just would like to fix it.

Comment: You need to change the title to follow what your explanation. What's your Android version? Do the device has enough memory? is the screen in perfect condition?